# Проблема со звуком

Tags: аудио, windows-8

После включения компьютера, на нем пропадает звук. Появляется после перезагрузки компьютера, либо звукового драйвера. Как исправить?

Comment: Возможно, стоит привести больше информации для обнаружения проблемы